Override shouldjs global typescript defintion
My current project utilizes should.js for assertions in tests. However, one of my types has a property called should, and in this case I need the property key to be should.
interface Include {
    must: ...;
    must_not: ...;
    should: ...;
}

Because the should.d.ts. file in node_modules/should declares the following global definition of an Object, I keep getting type errors because the should in my object using that type isn't should.Assertion.
declare global {
  interface Object {
    should: should.Assertion;
  }
}

My project directory looks like the below.
src/
test/
tsconfig.json
package.json
...

I'm hoping for some way to disable the should.js global type definition in the src directory.
